# Code in directory expects import

Tags: go, gopath

I have a package which is forked from a repository `myproject`. Inside the project, I want to use some functions from `sha3` package, however, I need to first add a `go` file to `sha3` package which contains some extra functionalities. I want to include this custom `sha3` package inside my project. I copied and pasted the `sha3` directory into `myproject` directory, and inside my `go` codes, I imported `sha3` package as:
`import . "github.com/myproject/sha3"`. Now, when I try to build `myproject` package, I am getting:
`code in directory /src/github.com/myproject/sha3 expects import "golang.org/x/crypto/sha3"`. I cannot understand what the problem is. I checked all the `go` files inside `sha3` directory and none of them requires any import!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

line number 66 sha3/docs.go has the import comment.

```
import "golang.org/x/crypto/sha3"
```

You can get rid of the build error by removing that.

Comment: OMG! I certainly did not know it considers comments as well! You're a lifesaver!

Comment: @A23149577: see the [Import Path Checking documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Import_path_checking)